# SQL multiple tables with COUNT function, greater than and a JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, count

I've got two tables: `CINEMA(Cinemano, Cname)` and `EMPLOYEE(Empno, Firstname, Surname, Cinemano)`.

I need to list the cinema names of cinemas which employ more than four employees

I tried doing this:

```
SELECT e.CINEMANO, c.CNAME, c.CINEMANO, COUNT(e.CINEMANO)
FROM EMPLOYEE e JOIN CINEMA c
ON (e.cinemano = c.cinemano)
GROUP BY c.CNAME
HAVING COUNT(e.CINEMANO) > 4;
```

Which apparently doesn't work saying 'not a GROUP BY expression'.

Comment: You need to remove both `CINEMANO` references in the Select.

Comment: A JOINT? What are you smoking? **Note**: A joke that needs to be explained is not a joke. But there may be non-English speakers reading this; for their benefit, https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=joint

Comment: Once you get an answer that is correct, or enables you to solve your problem, the site expects you to "Accept" an answer. It takes less than a second to do, just click a tick mark to the left of an answer. Only you can do this as it is your question. It denotes that the question is solved so we can move on to help others. You get 2 points for that acceptance by the way. Refer to [help] for more if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get just the cinemas with more than 4 employees:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CINEMA 
WHERE Cinemano in 
(
    SELECT Cinemano
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    GROUP BY Cinemano
    HAVING COUNT(*)>4
)
```

Still getting the name and count:

```
SELECT c.Cinemano, c.Cname, COUNT(*) EmployeeCount
FROM EMPLOYEE e 
    INNER JOIN CINEMA c ON e.Cinemano= c.Cinemano
GROUP BY c.Cinemano, c.Cname
HAVING COUNT(*) > 4;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat every column that *doesn't* have an aggregate function (such as `COUNT()` `MIN()` `MAX()` etc.) in the `group by` clause. so:

```
SELECT
      e.CINEMANO
    , c.CNAME
    , c.CINEMANO
    , COUNT(*)
FROM EMPLOYEE e
JOIN CINEMA c ON e.cinemano = c.cinemano
GROUP BY
      e.CINEMANO
    , c.CNAME
    , c.CINEMANO
HAVING COUNT(*) > 4
;
```

an alternative might be to use a `window function` instead like this:

```
SELECT
      e.CINEMANO
    , c.CNAME
    , c.CINEMANO
FROM (
      SELECT
            e.CINEMANO
          , c.CNAME
          , c.CINEMANO
          , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY e.CINEMANO) counter
      FROM EMPLOYEE e
      JOIN CINEMA c ON e.cinemano = c.cinemano
      ) d
WHERE counter > 4
;
```

Here the count is performed "over" each partition (and the result is available on each row of data) so you can filter on that calculation as shown.